# HP ProLiant ML10 v2 Debian compatability

Tags: debian, hp-proliant, drivers

Looking to replace my aging server (running Server 2003) and found this one on newegg. [HP ProLiant ML10 v2](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=2RC-001A-000S2) 
I see the [driver page](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=7796452&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=4138) shows CentOS, Red Hat, & SUSE compatible drivers.
But I was hoping to run Debian (its what I know). Would the drivers available from HP work with the Debian OS?
I'm not sure how cross friendly different distro's drivers are.

Comment: Probably not. Debian isn't designed for professional servers, and it very often does things very strangely, which is why many people avoid it and its descendants such as Ubuntu. Fortunately it shouldn't take you too long to unlearn any Debian-isms you may have picked up.

Comment: @MichaelHampton If [this](https://www.ubuntu.com/server) is not designed for servers, then what is it designed for?

Comment: @kasperd Making money for Canonical. But who said it wasn't designed for servers?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the official OS support listing for the ProLiant ML10 v2. Debian is not supported or recommended for use with HP hardware.

The OS would likely load, but you'd lose RAID controller support and wouldn't be able to use any of the HP monitoring utilities.

In situations where I NEED to run Debian, I'll virtualize using a supported hypervisor, then run Debian on top.

[image]

Comment: Isn't Ubuntu a derivative of Debian? Strange I didn't see Ubuntu drivers.

Comment: The drivers are in the kernel. Ubuntu support is really about HP's management utilities.